# laravel queries calculating average

Tags: laravel, controller, average, php-carbon

I want an average of all sales for the month of January in the whole table. My date_sold is in the format y/m/d. I may have many records eg 2016-01-23, 2015-01,14, 2017-01-05 all with their sales.
I want to get the average of the sales for a particular drug or drugs if they were sold in January. So far this is my controller but it is only picking the first record

```
$drug = $request->get('drug');
$stocks = DB::table('sales')
 ->join('drugs', 'drugs.id', '=', 'sales.drug_id')
 ->select('sales.*','drugs.name', DB::raw ('AVG(sales.quantity_sold) as average_sales'))
 ->whereIn('drug_id', $drug)
 ->whereMonth('complete_sold','=', Carbon::today()->month)
 ->get();
```

Comment: What contains `$drug` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add groupBy:

```
$drug = $request->get('drug');
$stocks = DB::table('sales')
 ->join('drugs', 'drugs.id', '=', 'sales.drug_id')
 ->select('sales.*','drugs.name', DB::raw ('AVG(sales.quantity_sold) as average_sales'))
 ->whereIn('drug_id', $drug)
 ->whereMonth('complete_sold','=', Carbon::today()->month)
 ->groupBy('drugs.id')
 ->get();
```